# Using WAAD and OWIN (for OAuth) in same website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I using Windows Azure Active Directory log in (WS-Federation) in my web site. Also I am trying to integrate OAuth login for Facebook, Linkedin, Google+, MS Live and Yahoo  from following post:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Problem is if I have configured WAAD login in my Web.Config file I can't use OAuth from that post, it breaks! If I turn of WAAD in Web.Config file, OAuth starts to work.

Is it possible to use WAAD and OWIN OAuth (from mentioned post) in same website and same project?
If is answer YES, can somebody give me some advice or instructions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's possible to use **OWIN** WAAD and OWIN OAuth in the same project.  [This walkthrough](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/28/use-owin-azure-ad-to-secure-both-mvc-ux-and-web-api-in-the-same-project/) shows how to do it with OpenID Connect instead of WS-Fed, but I would think using the OWIN WS-Fed module would work as well.

Comment: Thanks for your respond but I am not able to do this. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You're not able to do what? And why are you not able to do it?

Comment: e.g. WebApiConfig.Register I can't find it. Doesn't exist.

Comment: But in general you provide me good idea. I am trying with this approach because it is more similar to me: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WSFederation-DotNet

Comment: `WebApiConfig.Register` is only there because that sample has a REST API.  If you don't have an API you don't need it.  I'm glad you found another example that helped.